# React Router <redirect> not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have configured react-router to redirect any unknown url to "/":

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Shell}>
        <IndexRoute component={GithubPage}/>
        <Route path="clock" component={ClockPage}/>
        <Redirect from="*" to="/"/>
    </Route>
</Router>
```

The server has been correctly configured to redirect any unknown URLs to `/index.html`, which looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <main></main>
        <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**React Router 2.8.1 Behavior**

- `/clock` gets routed correctly to ClockPage
- `/clock/est` (which is an unknown route) does not even load the app. The server correctly sends `/index.html`, but the css and js files are not loaded because the browser is asking for `/clock/main.css` and `/clock/main.js` - which do not exist!
- To fix this issue I included `<base href="/">` in my index.html. Now the browser correctly asks for `/main.css` and `/main.js` and the app loads correctly. It also redirects to "/" because `/clock/est` is an unknown route. However I get this warning in the browser console:

> Warning: Automatically setting basename using `<base href>` is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release. The semantics of  are subtly different from basename. Please pass the basename explicitly in the options to createHistory

**React Router 3.0.0 Behavior**

At this point, I switched to react-router version 3.0.0 (keeping `<base href="/">`) and the warning goes away. The unknown route still correctly redirects to "/".

So my questions are:

1. Does react-router 3.0.0 now allow the use of `<base href>`
2. Is my solution the best way to redirect unknown URLs to "/"?

Assume that I will switch over to react-router 3.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

If you're generating out your CSS using WebPack and you're using the HtmlWebpackPlugin you can inject your CSS dependencies in your HTML template like so:

```
<% for (var css in htmlWebpackPlugin.files.css) { %>
  <link href="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.css[css] %>" rel="stylesheet">
<% } %>
```

Then you don't have to worry about using  in your template.